# wxWidgets makefile help needed

Tags: c++, makefile, wxwidgets, include-path

I'm trying to understand how I can write my own makefile for a wxWidgets application. I'm using MinGW on Windows and have already compiled wxWidgets.

Can somebody give me an example makefile which sets include directories for wxWidgets and works for multiple header and source files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you must use to compile your own applications are described in the last section of [docs/msw/install.txt](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser/wxWidgets/trunk/docs/msw/install.txt) file in your wxWidgets installation.

You can also look at the beginning of any `makefile.gcc` under `samples` directory, e.g. [this one](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/browser/wxWidgets/trunk/samples/minimal/makefile.gcc) to see the options you need to set, but there will be a lot of things you don't need there.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I copied a makefile from one of the samples, and changed the wxWidgets include paths. I have no clue what all the options mean whatsoever..

Comment: @Midas That's what documentation is for :D